# How to filter array with text and numbers

Tags: webdriver

Im have an array `["mother", "34343", "brother", "11", "22"`
and i need to confirm that all numbers from this array is less then 35000. How i can do it? Should i filter it somehow and exclude all words and then do `expect.to.be.below` then 35000?

```js
browser.waitUntil(() => {
    return  $$('[class="header-title"]').map((elem) => elem.isDisplayed()).length > 5;
}, { timeout: 10000, timeoutMsg:'5 users has not been displayed'});
const creatorName = [];
$$('[class="header-title"]').forEach(element => {
    creatorName.push(element.getText().toLowerCase());
})
    
creatorName.every((i) => expect(i).to.be.below("25000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` and `every` you can achieve it:

```js
const allNumbersLess3500 = arr => {
    return arr.filter(e => !isNaN(e)).every(n => n < 35000);
}

allNumbersLess3500(["words", "12", "come", "35001", "to"]); // -> false
allNumbersLess3500(["dont", "12", "easy", "350", "me"]); // -> true
```